# R Shiny - Cannot retrieve value of input control created inside DT Table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I was following this example from DT's official page to create input controls inside a DT table. I created something similar but I also needed an editable table. Due to which, I need to set `server = TRUE` in `renderDT` (Realized after RTFM that `reloadData` requires `server = TRUE`). So now I tried following this example of rendering checkbox input inside DT table but with `server = TRUE`. The issue is that now I am not able to fetch the values of input controls on server-side, which worked fine when `server = FALSE`. Can any one tell me how to retrieve the control values on the server side in this setup.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:5), nrow = 12, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:5])
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month.abb[i], m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = TRUE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Which part do you want to edit in the datatable?

Comment: The table I am using is different, it has select inputs in one column and then 12 columns (1 for each month) where the user can fill/edit the numbers. I am using the above code from DT's official page to demonstrate that input value retrieval does not work if you set `server = TRUE`. I want to figure out how to retrieve the values with `server = TRUE`.